# Como poner un color de fondo en mi pagina web

Tags: html, css, flask

Estoy diseñando una pagina web y no se por que me sale un color de fondo rojo en toda la pagina cuando yo lo he puesto rosado no encuentro el error en el código

Comment: Benvenida a o.s.es, podrias subir los codigos de tu pagina tanto el CSS si lo estas utiliznado para que puedan ayudarte o guiarte para que puedas solucionar tu problema. Gracias

Comment: Hola. Puede deberse a múltiples razones. Sería necesario que concretaras más, aportaras el código para poder reproducir tu problema, etc. También puedes leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

pueden ser por muchos factores como menciona un colega, pero si no podemos ver el código css no podremos ayudarte. Lo que podrías hacer es inspeccionar en el navegador y ver de donde proviene.

Answer (score 0):

vas a tu hoja de estilo css y agregas el siguiente codigo:

```
body {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, valora incluir una explicación sobre el porque de tu respuesta, como y porqué debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

con css simplemente

```
body{
background-color: pink;
}
```